# Apex strange exception handling

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I have a problem with my trigger. In Sandbox, everything works fine. When I deploy it to production, I receive multiple exceptions - which is really strange, because I got angry and put the whole code in "try" block. When I put everything in "try" block, it shouldn't be possible not to catch an exception!

This is how my code looks:

```
trigger UpdateLeadField on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    //debugging in progress
    try{
        if(Trigger.New[0].SomeField__c==NULL)
        {
            for(Lead obj: trigger.new)
                obj.SomeField__c = obj.OwnerId;
            return;
        }
    
        if (Trigger.New[0].OwnerId != Trigger.Old[0].OwnerId) 
        {
            for(Lead obj: trigger.new)
            {
                if(Trigger.New[0].SomeField__c==NULL || [SELECT Name FROM UserRole Where Id = :[SELECT Id, UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Id = :obj.OwnerId][0].UserRoleId].Name == 'Some role')
                obj.SomeField__c = obj.OwnerId;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.debug(e);
    }
}
```

The main problem seems to be with Web-to-Lead - When deployed, it stops working.
The exception:

> Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: 005C00000XXXXXX/00XXXXX0000LXXQ
>
> UpdateLeadField: data changed by trigger for field Some field: id value of incorrect type: 00GC00000XXXXXqMAC

"Some field" is a lookup field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Exception Cause**

The key issue that is causing that exception is that you are trying to assign a `Group` Id to a `User` Lookup. You need to make sure it is a `User` Id first.

```
if (obj.OwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType) obj.SomeField__c = obj.OwnerId;
```

**Why It Wasn't Caught**

The line where you assign the `OwnerId` does not cause an `Exception`. It causes the transaction to be invalid. Wherever you *perform this update* from is now throwing a `DmlException`. If you were doing the following it would be caught:

```
try
{
    someLead.OwnerId = someGroupId;
    update someLead;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

However the following causes no exception to be thrown:

```
try
{
    someLead.OwnerId = someGroup.Id; // valid
}
catch (Exception pokemon) // gotta catch 'em all!
{
    // do stuff
}
```

But as I explain below, getting frustrated and putting everything in a `try`/`catch` block is a really bad approach to solving this kind of problem, **especially if you don't take an action in your `catch` block**. It might hide it, but it will never solve it and will almost certainly make things worse down the line.

**Other Areas For Improvement**

You have a few code quality issues. For instance this pattern...

```
try
{
    // do several complex operations
}
catch (Exception pokemon) // gotta catch 'em all!
{
    // debug
}
```

is a recipe for headaches and confusion. First of all, you should always know a specific type of `Exception` you are expecting. In this instance, it should probably be `DmlException`. Second, you are failing  silently, and unit testing against this pattern has a high chance of passing when it should actually fail.

Another issue is that you have a query (or two) in a for loop:

```
SELECT Name FROM UserRole Where Id = :
[SELECT Id, UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Id = :obj.OwnerId][0].UserRoleId]
```

You should move these outside the loop, and probably not have nested queries in that way.

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Lead record : trigger.new) ownerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([
    SELECT UserRole.Name FROM User
    WHERE Id IN :ownerIds
]);
for (Lead record : trigger.new)
{
    User owner = userMap.get(record.OwnerId);
    if (owner != null && owner.UserRole.Name == 'Some Role')
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

A third problem with your code is that you are checking conditions on `trigger.new[0]`, then acting on the whole collection. This is going to lead to very inconsistent behavior. You should apply a filter to the whole collection, then act in a certain way on that subset. For example, each record without `Somefield__c` populated should have `X` happen, each record where the `OwnerId` changed should have `Y` happen.

One last recommendation, move your functionality to `static` methods in an `Apex Class`. It is not the best idea to have a bunch of code in your triggers. For one thing, it makes the functionality much more difficult to test. If you had the following it would be much easier to asses the functionality in a unit test:

```
public with sharing class LeadServices
{
    public static void populateSomeField(List<Lead> leads)
    {
        for (Lead lead : leads) lead.SomeField__c = lead.OwnerId;
    }
    public static List<Lead> filterLeadsToPopulateSomeField
        (List<Lead> newRecords, Map<Id, Lead> oldMap)
    {
        List<Lead> toPopulate = new List<Lead>();
        for (Lead lead : newRecords)
        {
            if (!isOwnedByUser(lead)) continue;
            else if (lead.SomeField__c == null) toPopulate.add(lead);
            else if (lead.OwnerId != oldMap.get(lead.Id).OwnerId) toPopulate.add(lead);
        }
        return toPopulate;
    }
    public static Boolean isOwnedByUser(Lead lead)
    {
        return lead.OwnerId != null &&
            lead.OwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! But the main question remains: why the catch {} block didn't caught it? Everything is in there! In any other language, this exception wouldn't be unhandled.

Comment: Yeah the assignment itself is valid. It just leads to an invalid transaction which gets caught when committing to the database.

Comment: @SayMyName It should be noted that there are some exceptions that can't be caught.  Unfortunately the Salesforce docs on exceptions doesn't list them, but the big example I know of is `LimitException`s, which are thrown when you hit a governor limit.

Comment: @Namfuak It does seem somewhat obvious that `LimitException` cannot be caught. I am not sure if there are any others.

Comment: @AdrianLarson From [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_2.htm): `Some exceptions can’t be handled, such as exceptions that the runtime throws as a result of reaching a governor limit.`  This seems to imply that there are exceptions which are not governor limit exceptions that also cannot be caught - I'd imagine an internal database error might cause this, for example.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I started rewriting the code, then you edited the post and recommended me to create a class. Now I got really confused - could you, please show me, how the trigger will look, when methods from the class you provided will be used? I am sorry, if that's too much.

Comment: You would just call `LeadServices.populateSomeField(filterLeadsToPopulateSomeField(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap))`.

Comment: @SayMyName You'd just prefix them with the class name, IE `LeadServices.populateSomeField(leads);`.  One other advantage is that this allows you to call them from outside the trigger - `isOwnedByUser` could be useful elsewhere, for example.

Comment: You will change lead's ownerId, if it's the field is null:

if (lead.SomeField__c == null) 
         toPopulate.add(lead); 

Won't this throw an exception again? There's no checking, if it's not a group.

Comment: Thanks! I also need to check the role. Where should I do that? In the "filterLeadsToPopulateSomeField" function? I am asking, because I don't want to make the same mistake again - query in a loop.

Comment: This is not a form where you have people do all the work for you, and my code sample was not meant to be complete. You should try to implement, and if you run into struggles, post them as separate questions. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to merge that logic (already provided) into the filter method.